# WHat is the shortkey to replace "_" to "|" while typing any programme?

Tags: java, editor

By mistake while typing code I pressed something and my cursor "|" replaced with "_".

Comment: It depends what editor you're using

Comment: Are you talking _insert_ vs. _overwrite/replace_ mode? It's usually the <Insert> key.

Comment: this is not the right format of question for this site, but if i had to guess, it would be the "insert" key on your keyboard

Comment: You had pressed `insert` key, press it again to get back to normal cursor.

Comment: I am using online editor for java. Insert key that was. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Mrunal! This question is off-topic for this site. That's why you are getting downvotes. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Try the insert key.
It selects if a sign gets shifted or replaced.
[image]